# Form validation for multiple input fields by combining variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have a form that uses javascript form validation and instead of listing each variable and what to validate it against per variable, I am trying to combine all of those variables into one variable and then have them validate against a singular list of elements.

I was trying initially to assign all of the input fields to a class and have them validate against the class instead of the name element but I could not get that to work so I am trying this.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
   function validateForm() {
      var x = document.forms["myForm"]["input1"].value;
      var y = document.forms["myForm"]["input2"].value;
      var z = x + y;
      if (z == "123CODE" || z == "125CODE") {
        return true;} 
      else if (z != "123CODE" || z != "125CODE") {
        alert("Please enter a valid code"); return false;}

      }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp"
onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="input1">
      <input type="text" name="input2">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jquery is allowed?? or pure javascript??

Comment: I am open to jquery if it works the way I want it to  @GuruprasadRao

Comment: you have a syntax error , extra '}' at end, remove that it will work as expected

Comment: Check this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/zdtzfzc1/)** and let me know if this is what you want??

Comment: @Holodout you dont want to access element with name , instead you want class to access ?

Comment: @AnirbanN yes! if I could have it access by class that would work great!

Comment: @Holodout.. How about this - **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/zdtzfzc1/1/)**

Comment: Simultaneously if you code is not case sensitive you can write your if condition as - `if (z.trim().toLowerCase() == "123code" || z.trim().toLowerCase() == "125code")`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao after reviewing your first fiddle I realized that it was correct! If you answer the question with this solution I will mark it answered :)

Comment: Posted my first fiddle and code as answer! :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao the FIRST fiddle is correct, this one:

http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/zdtzfzc1/

please revise your answer

Comment: That's what I posted there!! Check the DEMO link!!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Oh, ok it was missing the console.log(z); line in the answer but the demo link is correct, thanks!

Comment: That wasn't necessary. That was just for reference!! :) Anyways!! Happ Coding.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be your javascript submit function:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/zdtzfzc1/)**

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["input1"].value;
    var y = document.forms["myForm"]["input2"].value;
    var z = x + y;
    if (z == "123CODE" || z == "125CODE") 
    {
        return true;
    } 
    else
    {
       alert("Please enter a valid code"); 
       return false;
    }
}
```

Simultaneously if your code is not case sensitive you can write your if condition as -

```
if (z.trim().toLowerCase() == "123code" || z.trim().toLowerCase() == "125code")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (z.search("123CODE")>0 || z.search("125CODE")>0)
{
}
```

you can write if statement like this if the search result is > 0 then condition will be true otherwise false.